# The optimal way to assign a set of letters to a specific number

Tags: combinatorics

Below are twelve pairs where the x-coordinate is a set of 3 numbers and the $y$-coordinate is a set of sets of letters.

$$
\begin{array}{l}
(\{6, 1, 4\},~ \{\{A\}, \{E\}\}) \\
(\{3, 4, 5\},~ \{\{A\}, \{E\}\})\\
(\{6, 4, 5\},~ \{\{E\}, \{A\}, \{E, A\}\}) \\
(\{6, 2, 5\},~ \{\{E\}, \{A\}, \{A, E\}\})\\
(\{6, 2, 1\},~ \{\{E\}, \{E, A\}, \{A\}\})\\
(\{0, 2, 1\},~ \{\{A\}\}) \\
(\{0, 1, 4\},~ \{\{A\}\}) \\
(\{0, 2, 5\},~ \{\{A\}\}) \\
(\{0, 4, 5\},~ \{\{A\}\}) \\
(\{2, 1, 3\},~ \{\{A\}, \{E\}\}) \\
(\{1, 3, 4\},~\{\{C\}\}) \\
(\{2, 3, 5\},~ \{\{E\}, \{A\}\})\\
\end{array}
$$
Between all these pairs, there are some repeated numbers in x-coordinates and in the same way there are some set of the letters are repeated.
My question is: What is the optimal way to assignee a set of letters to a specific number in such a way that:

•   A minimum number of the numbers in x- coordinates are used.
•   All the sets of letters must be assigned to number/numbers.

What I am looking for a way to find a solution as the following:

({4}, {{A},{E},{E,A},{C}})
({5}, {{E}, {A}, {A,E}})
({11},{{E},{E,A},{A})

Thank you, 
Hanan

Comment: It's not readable.

Comment: { {a}, {b} } is not a set of letters.  { a,b } is.

Comment: By {{a},{b}}, I mean a set that consists of two sets {a} and {b}. It seams like a set of sets . and {a,b} is a set of two letters.

Comment: I am confused as to how this is a general topology question.